# Is giving child ride considered spoiling?

Tags: transport

My sister lives 15-20min walk from her school but my mom gives her a ride in the car every morning.  Is this considered spoiling the child or no.  In my opinion it is because I think it's a perfectly close enough distance to walk.

Comment: What is the age of the child? What is culturally appropriate? Is giving the child a ride practical or is this accommodation inconvenient? How responsible is the child when alone? If your intention is for the child not to walk alone, is there anyone available who can do this? Without more information, I'm afraid this is pretty opinion based.

Comment: age = high school.  Not really interested in culturally appropriate or not but if it is the right thing to do to benefit her when she becomes adult.  Also inconvience is not a problemo if giving her a ride is good for her.

Comment: Social factors are relevant here though, so what is culturally appropriate and what is practical for the parent *will* affect what is good for her.

Comment: Also the responsibility level of the child, if there are friends in the area who would be walking with her, and (this is really important) what AREA. What is the location of this? What country, what city, what part of the city? You don't have to and shouldn't disclose all this to us online, but it is important to give context to your question. Is it a rural suburb of a safe-ish area in Canada? Is it the "hood" in a big city in America? Is it Japan where 5yos go to school alone?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention if there is a pedestrian-safe path to school, or if there are any other safety issues ( a girl walking alone might be subject to harassment, for instance)

Comment: Yes it is very pedestrian safe.  Just an average safety neighborhood in my opinion.

Comment: "Average safety" where?  I have lived in 5 countries (US, Canada, PNG, Colombia, Peru) and I would not choose to let my teen-age daughter walk outside, alone, for even three blocks, much less a mile, in any of them.  When you get to be a parent, and if you have had to deal with child safety enforcement, as I have, maybe you will understand that "average safety" is not good enough.

Comment: @Agapwlesu is there some reason you consistently live in such awful neighborhoods that you wouldn't let your teenager walk a mere three blocks? I live (in the USA) a few blocks from an elementary school, and I often see the older (pre-teen) kids walking home by themselves.

Comment: In my area of the US  all of the schools are on major roads - not designed for walking students. It's sad, but you have to get special dispensation for your child to be allowed to walk home from school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading a news article recently about a teenage girl that was abducted while walking with some friends.  A van stopped in front of the group, men jumped out and they grabbed one of the girls.  My own daughters, when they were ages 5 and 8 were playing in my front yard when they were almost abducted.  If I had not noticed the car coming to a quick stop and the passenger jumping out and rushing at them, I'd still be searching for them.  Fortunately I was just on the other side of a hedge and ran around it before he could lay hands on them.  He turned a fast 180, jumped back in the car and the driver peeled off.  They unfortunately got away.

Unfortunately, in this day and age, security can be a very big factor in decisions like this, especially for girls.

But, I think you should ask whether it is your place to question your parents' decision on this.  As your parents, they have far more experience than you, and a decision like this is never as simple as "you can walk, you should".

There are certainly other factors.  Where we live, we could have my daughters ride the school bus to and from school, but my wife likes to drop them off and pick them up.  Picking them up from school gives her an opportunity to interact with them and hear about their day at school.  Yes, it is more work, but she considers it worth it.

If I were you, I'd put this out of my mind.  It is for your parents to decide how best to handle that situation.

Comment: Statistically speaking, it is safer today than it has been in the past 50 years. It is sad that you personally have experienced a near abduction, but such an event is very rare and, and more rare today than it was 50 years ago when I was growing up.

Comment: @pojo-guy - how would you know that?  Statistics on this sort of thing were near non-existant 50 years ago.  The data would be so splotchy it would be ridiculous to try to make a comparison.  And awareness also has had a lot of impact on changing statistics.  Child safety crimes (abduction is not the only concern) that went largely under-reported 50 years ago are now reported more.  However, even today reporting is far from 100%.  Statistically speaking, you can say nothing to compare 50 years ago and now, nor would a comparison, even if accurate, matter.  How much risk, today, is acceptable?

Comment: Looking for hard numbers, since you asked.  It'll be a bit.

Comment: Link #1: https://www.cnn.com/2012/05/25/opinion/lanning-missing-children/index.html - by former FBI investigator   Link #2: http://www.bbc.com/news/education-30578830 does not address abduction in particular, but childrens as victims of violent crime in general

Comment: Link #3: https://psmag.com/education/the-kids-really-are-all-right-58651